# MySQL query with specific timezone

Tags: mysql, timezone

I have a database storing data for my Laravel/PHP application. All data is stored in the database as UTC.

I'm writing a query to get data grouped by date and hour so I can plot the data on a graph.

Our UI shows reporting data in the `America/Los_Angeles` timezone.

What I'm looking to do is get the last three days data but queried based on the reporting timezone of `America/Los_Angeles`.

To get the `BETWEEN` dates I'm using the below

```
$from = now()
    ->startOfDay()
    ->subDays(3)
    ->timezone('America/Los_Angeles');

$to = now()
    ->endOfDay()
    ->timezone('America/Los_Angeles');
```

This works OK. So the next step is grouping the data but not grouping it on the column data as that would be `UTC`. I would like to group is on the `Los_Angeles` timezone. So I'm doing the below.

```
SELECT
  DATE(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS grouped_date,
  HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS grouped_hour,
  count(*) AS requests
FROM
  `advert_requests`
WHERE
  created_at BETWEEN '2022-09-09 17:00:00' AND '2022-09-13 16:59:59'
GROUP BY
  grouped_date,
  grouped_hour
```

The random issue I'm having is that the grouped data is starting on `2022-09-09` at `10:00` and I'm not sure why.

Starting the `BETWEEN` at `2022-09-09 17:00:00 America/Los_Angeles` is `2022-09-10 00:00:00 UTC` so when doing the `CONVERT_TZ` on the `created_at` shouldn't the grouped data start at `0`?

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely this isn't as easy as just setting the timezone to the reporting timezone for the sessions where I run the reporting `SELECT` query.

So I can leave everything else as `UTC`. My application is `UTC` and handles timezone conversion in the php/application. My database is set to `UTC`. My MySQL `INSERT`'s etc are all `UTC`. Then when I want to query anything to be displayed in our UI using our fixed reporting timezone of `America/Los_Angeles` I can just set it before running the `SELECT` query?

```
SET time_zone = '-07:00';

// In the Laravel framework
// DB::update('SET time_zone = ?', ['-07:00']);
```

And then

```
SELECT
  DATE(created_at) AS grouped_date,
  HOUR(created_at) AS grouped_hour,
  count(*) AS requests
FROM
  `advert_requests`
WHERE
  created_at BETWEEN '2022-09-10 00:00:00'
  AND '2022-09-13 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
  grouped_date,
  grouped_hour
```

Comment: It depends on whether the data type for your `created_at` column is `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME`. If it's `TIMESTAMP`, then it is always stored in UTC, and converted automatically from/to the session timezone during insert and fetch. If it's `DATETIME`, the value is stored exactly according to the literal value you used when you inserted it. The conversion does not happen, so you'd have to use CONVERT_TZ() yourself.

Comment: Thanks Bill, this is fantastic. My answer to my own query is working perfectly now then and saving me a HUGE amount of query time.